# How do I return the search term within a Django's Generic Class Based ListView

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I would like to return the search term along with the search results. I did try to add the search term within the context dictionary and tried to return the context object, but that doesn't work. When I just return the search results without the search term, it works perfectly.

Could anyone please help me on how I could return the search term, along with the search results. Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Below is my code for your kind reference.

```
class JobSearchView(ListView):
    model               = Job
    template_name       = 'jobs/job_search_results.html'
    ordering            = ['-published_date']
    context_object_name = 'search_results'
    paginate_by         = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        search_results = []
        distinct_search_results = []
        query = self.request.GET.get('search_term')
        keyword_list = query.split(" ")
        print(keyword_list)
        for keyword in keyword_list:
            print(keyword)
            posts = Job.objects.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=keyword) |
                Q(organization__name__icontains=keyword) |
                Q(type__icontains=keyword) |
                Q(address__icontains=keyword) |
                Q(city__icontains=keyword) |
                Q(state__name__icontains=keyword) |
                Q(pincode__icontains=keyword) |
                Q(min_qualification__icontains=keyword) |
                Q(desired_qualification__icontains=keyword) |
                Q(profession__name__icontains=keyword) |
                Q(department__name__icontains=keyword)
            ).distinct()

            for post in posts:
                search_results.append(post)

        context = {
            'search_query': query,
            'search_results': search_results
        }

        return context
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? `search_query` is the search term that you added to the context, so printing `{{ search_query }}` in your template should work.

Comment: Oh, you should return the context in `get_context_data()` not in `get_queryset()`.

Comment: @dirkgroten I would like to invoke this JobSearchView function using an anchor tag (<a>) with a static value assigned for the search term, how do I do that? Thanks in advance again!

Comment: `href="{% url 'job_search' %}?search_term=all"` where "job_search" is the name of your url pattern and "all" is whatever static search term you want.

Comment: @dirkgroten All I can say is you are genius :) Once again thank you so much for the quick and precise answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `get_context_data()` to add the search query to the context, not `get_queryset()`.